# Issue with size on simulator and size in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode-storyboard

I didn't quite understand the whole freeform / fixed simulated sizes of the view controller and now I am having some weird issues with my project.
[image]

In this case i made it look like this and when I run the project it looks something like this :
[image]

I set up the constraints and everything but I thing it has something to do with the simulated size and everything

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using autolayout? If so, can you list or screenshot the constraints you're using?

Comment: now it's ok.but I have one question to ask you.what does inferred and freeform do in simulated size?